# How to Deploy Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, tomcat, ubuntu-14.04, jruby

I am new to Rails, I have created a rails application, where I am using 
jruby 1.7.16 and database PostgreSQL.Please suggest me what are the best way to deploy the application.I want to deploy the application in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and access using ip address.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Capistrano but you may have hard times in setting it up for the first time.

There are plenty of information on Internet about deploying your app with Capistrano but since version 3 have been released recently, be careful with the tutorials for older versions. Many things have changed after version 3

I hope it helps